# .NET MAUI Windows control box is opposite

Tags: c#, .net, maui

.NET MAUI Windows control box is opposite and you can't click the minimize, maximize or close button.
But when you move the curser to the opposite direction you'll see the buttons color changes as like you're hovering on them. See the rest in this picture.
Is there a way to fix it?[image]

I looked for ways in Microsoft docs but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `See the rest in this video.` What video?

Comment: Do you try to run another project? Is this a common issue on the platform for you?

Comment: Other projects are fine
It's just MAUI windows

Comment: I mean all the MAUI windows occur this issue or only this MAUI window occurs this issue?

Comment: If all the MAUI windows occur this issue, this might be something wrong with the MAUI. I think you can update your visual studio version.

Comment: its all the MAUI windows projects and I updated visual studio, it's still unsolved

Comment: I post the answer it will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a verified maui issue. You can follow up the issue [On Windows (WinUI) Minimize, Normal, Maximize buttons behave strangely](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7751).

**Someone gives the solution and this is an RTL Bug. You can refer to [this link about changing  language/region settings](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7751#issuecomment-1156776600) to solve the issue by changing the Regional format.**

Comment: yes its a regional bug. by changing my region to USA, it got fix